# android how to write click event of an ImageView

Tags: android, onclick, imageview

I have an alarm symbol on my interface. I want it like if anyone clicks on this then he/she can get another interface.
so how to write a click event of Imageview. plz give me answer.  Thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can add an `OnClickListener` to `ImageView` using `setOnClickListener` method on your `ImageView` and write your code in the listener's `onClick` method.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(imageView)) {
            // Write your awesome code here
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Where should this go, in the onCreate() method?

Comment: Ya u can have it in onCreate() method itself

Answer (score 9):

Faster.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Your code.
    }
});
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: @abarisone It is already explained in before answer. I just commented a shortcut to economise code

Answer (score 1):

> with lambda expression

```
img_drawer_open_icon.setOnClickListener(v -> Home.drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START));
```

Comment: this is the Fastest :-)

Answer (score 0):

Also just do it in some easy steps visually:
1- Click your Image
2- From Attribute, Select OnClick and Type a Name Such as onCkick_btnST
3- In code of Your xml, find and select the above verb
4- using yellow bulb menu, select "Create OnClick Event Handler"
5- Fill your Code in created area.
The benefit of this methode is that U`LL see that event title in structure tab of Android Studio!